# VBA: How to filter through a sheet based on a checkbox?

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, autofilter

I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to set up a customizable sheet that allows the user to filter certain columns based on the checkboxes that I have set up. So far, I understand how checkboxes work and how I can integrate them into the code, but I think I have an issue with the autofilter function. Specifically, I think that I'm putting the wrong value for Criteria1.

I've been looking around for similar coding problems, but none of them seem to work with what I'm trying to do.

TL;DR I think my issue lies with how I format the array to put in Criteria1 of the AutoFilter()

```
Sub Auto_filter()

'variables are for checkboxes'
    Dim VC1500 As Shape 
    Dim VC7500 As Shape
    Dim VC144024 As Shape

'initiates to check for the checkboxes'
   Set VC1500 = Sheets("Sheet7").Shapes("Check Box 4")
   Set VC7500 = Sheets("Sheet7").Shapes("Check Box 5")
   Set VC144024 = Sheets("Sheet7").Shapes("Check Box 6")

'if statement that will add a string to strCriteria if checkbox is true'
    If VC1500.OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
       strCriteria = strCriteria & ", VC1500"
    End If

    If VC7500.OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
       strCriteria = strCriteria & ", VC7500"
    End If

    If VC144024.OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
       strCriteria = strCriteria & ", 144024"
    End If

'with statement that finds for column vendor then filter it based on 
strCriteria, I think this is where my issue is'

    With Worksheets("Open Purchase Orders")
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
            Set vendorfind = .Rows(1).Find("Vendor")
            If Not vendorfind Is Nothing Then
                .AutoFilter Field:=vendorfind.Column, 
           Criteria1:=Split(strCriteria, ", "), Operator:=xlFilterValues
            End If
        End With
         .AutoFilterMode = False
   End With

End Sub
```

I expect to have the sheet filtered based on the checkboxes. 
I get a runtime error 9 error:subscript out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some parts of that code look to me like scratching your left ear with your right hand going over your head. But I'm not entirely clear on how it actually looks (a sample would be helpful) - does each vendor have some separate indication column? If so, what are you filtering there? A vendor tag, by the looks of it?

This for example is a solution for a single vendor column (D) which may contain the 3 names. It basically applies an autofilter of a list of values. (I'm using activex checkboxes below as their properties can be accessed directly.)

```
Private Sub VC1500_Click()
Update_Filter
End Sub

Private Sub VC7500_Click()
Update_Filter
End Sub

Private Sub VC144024_Click()
Update_Filter
End Sub

Private Sub Update_Filter()
Dim varr_filter(3) As String
Dim indshow As Boolean
indshow = True
If VC1500 Then
    varr_filter(0) = VC1500.Caption
    indshow = False
End If
If VC7500 Then
    varr_filter(1) = VC7500.Caption
    indshow = False
End If
If VC144024 Then
    varr_filter(2) = VC144024.Caption
    indshow = False
End If
If indshow Then
    Range("$A:$D").AutoFilter
Else
    Range("$A:$D").AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=varr_filter, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End If
End Sub
```

Note: Pick the correct column for filtering as the "field" value, and if you wish to separate the checkboxes from the form for some reason, then add """sheets("sheetname").{each checkbox}""".

Alternatively, if each of the vcs possesses a separate column, and seeking rows which literally say "vendor", I'd merge them in the sheet like so:

```
E2=if(cond1)*checkbox1 + if(cond2)*checkbox2 + if(cond3)*checkbox3 ; E > 0.
Cond1 could be b2="Vendor", for example.
To make the sheet display all cols when no ticks are selected,
I've added another value: 1 - max(checkboxes).
E6=1-MAX($H$4:$H$6) + IF(AND(B2="Vendor"),1,0)*$H$4 +
   IF(AND(C2="Vendor"),1,0)*$H$5 + IF(AND(D2="Vendor"),1,0)*$H$6
```

That's one example where a hidden sheet value helps, since you can actually define such a column without vb. And then, the code itself is simplified a bit.

```
Private Sub VC1500_Click()
If VC1500.Value Then
    Range("$H$4").Value = 1
Else
    Range("$H$4").Value = 0
End If
Update_Filter
End Sub

Private Sub VC7500_Click()
If VC7500.Value Then
    Range("$H$5").Value = 1
Else
    Range("$H$5").Value = 0
End If
Update_Filter
End Sub

Private Sub VC144024_Click()
If VC144024.Value Then
    Range("$H$6").Value = 1
Else
    Range("$H$6").Value = 0
End If
Update_Filter
End Sub

Private Sub Update_Filter()
Range("$A:$E").AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:=">0", Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

It's also easier to transition to a form control, by checking the range value during click instead of the checkbox, and hiding column H. Not entirely bulletproof yet sufficient for the average user. Either that or read the shape as you wrote.

---

Edit: Added tested code above for both cases (single col, multicol), including displaying all rows when no tickboxes are checked rather than none. Here are the demo shots.

[Single col code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9tCI.png)

[Single col sample sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/airHu.png)

[Single col filtered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz7co.png)

[Multicol code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP9a2.png)

[Multicol sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82Iyq.png)

[Multicol filtered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk4Eq.png)

Comment: I'm actually using form controls, but like I said before I'm still getting the hang of this. I'm not really understanding the code you provided- if you don't mind breaking it down, that would be appreciated.

Comment: As for the purpose of this filter, I can try to elaborate more. So, the worksheet has information for everyone in my work, but they're responsible for their specific vendors. I'm trying to make a customizable filter based on vendor code and manufacturer #, and then another filter for specific columns that they find useful (this part will be easy as it should just be individual find functions tied to a checkbox for each column they want). I actually got the original code to work, but found myself with another problem with a runtime error 5.

Comment: Right, I misinterpreted - that's the reason for all the shape & ole fiddling. The code simply applies a filter to a single column with the selected vendor values. I've added a demo for it and a full guide for the multicol route, let me know if that clarifies things sufficiently. If it's all the same to you, by sample I meant a few lines of the sheet you have, and what you'd like the output to look like. I don't see details too well from explanations alone.

Comment: Wow, your code seems is cleaner than mine. I also suspect that it filters in real time? Since, by clicking on the checkbox, it runs the filter code.Also, thank you for the explanations and samples! It's pretty cool that there's other (better) ways to go on about this. I actually got mine to work, just some spacing issues with the string array. It's just a hassle since there's around 150 vendor codes, so I made a code to write it all up for me.

Comment: Yeah, it's real time. I'm strict wherever it comes to minimal user effort; with 150 vendors I'd definitely try to devise a strategy with the client to lessen the tedium. But if you managed to get it working eventually, that's an important landmark. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Slices?
Its easy and should do simple filters without Macros.

Select your data > Insert Table.
Once the table is done, from the Design tab you can select "Insert Slicer".
Try if this solves your problem.

Comment: I just looked into Slices, but I don't think it's what I'm looking for with all the data I have. Thank you for your input, though.